# cx_Freeze converted exe: window closes immediately

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, cx-freeze

I am trying to just convert my pygame python py to a .exe file using cx_Freeze. The setup file executes correctly and without error, but the issue is that when I run my .exe file the console window (the black cmd-like window)will open quickly and close. My .py which I want to convert is called Salary.py, and it includes a .input('str') codes in it so that the
user can decide which csv file they want to use.
Description of my Salary.py: if the user input an interger, Salary.py help them to parse through one existed csv file and run the 
script and output to another csv file.
Chinese is included inside the code.
Once again, there is no error running when I run Salary.py in python3.6, and no error when building the exe file for  now.

The setup.py I am using:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'D:\Anaconda3\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'D:\Anaconda3\tcl\tcl8.6'
setup(name='Salary',
      version='0.1',
      description='Salarycount',
      executables= [Executable("Salary.py")])
```

I try to execute the Salary.exe in cmd. And it gave this to me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 14, in run
    module.run()
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26, in run
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "Salary.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
"Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

Apperently, numpy has already installed to my python packages, I don't even know what does it mean.
my environment:
Anaconda 3
python 3.6
cx-Freeze      6.0b1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Salary.py script uses the `pandas` package, is this correct? The `pandas` package requires the `numpy` package to work, and one needs to tell cx_Freeze explicitly to include the `numpy` package. Try to add the following `options` to `setup`:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'D:\Anaconda3\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'D:\Anaconda3\tcl\tcl8.6'
setup(name='Salary',
      version='0.1',
      description='Salarycount',
      options={'build_exe': {'packages': ['numpy']}},
      executables= [Executable("Salary.py")])
```